# is this a bug of nginx: open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/testproxy.php" failed

Tags: nginx

i am new to nginx, yesterday i installed lemp on centos and hosted a website on. today i get this in error message. please tell me if this is a security bug of nginx? Thank you!

cat /var/log/nginx/error.log
2017/07/01 03:52:18 [error] 6073#0: *23151 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/testproxy.php" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 91.196.50.33, server: _, request: "GET http://testp3.pospr.waw.pl/testproxy.php HTTP/1.1", host: "testp3.pospr.waw.pl"

Answer (score 0):

It's not an nginx bug: If you're currently running a site that's live and accessible on the internet, bot scripts will try to find common vulnerabilities by hitting your server with various automated requests of common URLs, paths and patterns (e.g. `admin.php`, `/wp-login.php` for WordPress blogs...). Just make sure you set up proper security for your server and you'll be fine.

Comment: /usr/share/nginx/html/ is the defaut web folder of nginx what is home of http://my_ip/ .If you know this is not a bug so how can i re-generate that error log?